# NRefactory capable of parsing .NET 4.6?

Tags: c#, nrefactory

I have been successfully using NRefactory and just started having problems parsing source code that uses some newer .NET features. One feature in particular that I have noticed is string interpolation. When NRefactory sees something like `$"File: {myFile}"` it has total failure parsing it.
Is there a new version of the code that will handle dot-NET 4.6 or is there a flag that I need to set? If not, is there another easy way to get parse trees from source code?

If I wanted to use Roslyn, is there a way to do this with VS 2015 or is VS 2017 or later required? Tried opening Roslyn SLN in VS 2015 and none of the projects loaded.

Answer (score 0):

NRefactory does not support C# 6 or newer features, which would impact string interpolation.  According to [NRefactory](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/),

> There is currently no maintainer for NRefactory.  If you need a C#
>   parser / compiler frontend, use Microsoft.CodeAnalysis (Roslyn)
>   instead.
>
> The refactorings in NRefactory have been ported to Roslyn:
>       https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials/

You can use Roslyn with Visual Studio 2015, as long as you have .NET 4.6 or higher installed, though  4.7.2 is the recommended version to use by Roslyn team.  Lastly, you will need to the [following](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Visual-Studio-2015):

> Install Universal Windows App Development Tools -> Tools (1.1.1) and
>   Windows SDK, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 tools -> Tools and
>   Windows SDKs and Visual Studio Extensibility Tools
>   [image: Visual Studio 2015 install for Roslyn]

Comment: All of the listed prerequisites were already included in my installation. But when opening the SLN at the specified URL, 2 of the projects would not open including the most important, the Refactoring Essentials project.

When you say "You can use Roslyn with Visual Studio 2015" not sure if you mean as an add-in or as a DLL to use in other solutions. It is the latter I am interested in.

Would like to be able to run the Demonstration app that is in the SLN but again, without being able to successfully load the main code that is not possible.